# is $[a,b]\supset(a,b)$ true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

is $[a,b]\supset(a,b)$ true or false?
 i'm saying it's true but my teacher said it is false, and he wants a german reference to accept it. 
Thank you.

Comment: it is true, why does your teacher disagree??

Comment: $(a,b)$ does *not* include points $\{a,b\}$ while $[a,b]$ does.

Comment: The conventions are different for $(a,b)$, e.g., some people also write $]a,b[$, but for $[a,b]$ there should be no issue - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)).

Comment: TRUE. For every $x$, if $x \in (a,b)$, then $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: To be clear, it depends on what the symbols here represent.  The most common usage of the symbols here would be for $(a,b)$ to be in reference to the set of all real numbers strictly above $a$ and strictly below $b$, $\{x\in\Bbb R~:~a<x<b\}$ while $[a,b]$ would be in reference to $\{x\in\Bbb R~:~a\leq x\leq b\}$ where it wasn't strict inequalities used.  Then $\subset$ would be in reference to being a subset of (*or for some authors a proper subset of*).  With these interpretations of symbols, $(a,b)\subset [a,b]$ and $[a,b]\supset (a,b)$, are true.

Comment: It is possible you copied the problem incorrectly.  $[a,b]\subset (a,b)$ is indeed false since $[a,b]$ contains elements which are not contained in $(a,b)$, but again as it is currently written it is true (*namely the endpoint $a$ and the endpoint $b$ themselves*)

Comment: See [Notation for intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals) and compare with [German translation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervall_(Mathematik)#Beschr%C3%A4nkte_Intervalle).

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass du irgendeine Referenz finden wirst, die das explizit bestätigt. Das ist im Wesentlichen eine Frage der Definition/Notation. Aus $a < x < b$ folgt $a \leq x \leq b$ wird glaube ich nicht angezweifelt.

Comment: Why does he want a German reference?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde No he isn't German but he said he only trust in German
he doesn't want me to get the answer easily,and i lost 2 marks in the test.

Comment: You need a German reference? Here: das ist wahr.

Answer (score 5):

The German wikipedia entry [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervall_(Mathematik)) explains the notations of open, half-open, closed intervals. It agrees with the [English entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)).

\begin{align}
{\color{Red}(} a,b{\color{Red})}  = \mathopen{\color{Red}]}a,b\mathclose{\color{Red}[} &= \{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\mathbin{\color{Red}<}x\mathbin{\color{Red}<}b\}, \\{}
{\color{DarkGreen}[}a,b{\color{Red})}  = \mathopen{\color{DarkGreen}[} a,b\mathclose{\color{Red}[} &= \{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\mathbin{\color{DarkGreen}\le} x\mathbin{\color{Red}<}b\}, \\{}
{\color{Red}(} a,b{\color{DarkGreen}]} = \mathopen{\color{Red}]}a,b\mathclose{\color{DarkGreen}]} &= \{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\mathbin{\color{Red}<}x\mathbin{\color{DarkGreen}\le} b\}, \\{}
{\color{DarkGreen}[}a,b{\color{DarkGreen}]} = \mathopen{\color{DarkGreen}[} a,b\mathclose{\color{DarkGreen}]} &= \{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\mathbin{\color{DarkGreen}\le} x\mathbin{\color{DarkGreen}\le} b\}.
\end{align}

Comment: You're seeing $a{<}x{<}b$ rather than $a<x<b,$ i.e. there is a lack of proper spacing, because of your way of altering the colors of the binary relation symbols. And the color differences are barely visible.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have changed "Maroon" to "Red". Is it better? We should change it at the wikipedia page, too.

Comment: That's conspicuous; maroon was not.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the correct spacing can be obtained with `x\mathbin{R}y` $x\mathbin{R}y$ compare with `x{R}y` $x{R}y$. (`bin` for binary operator, of course) I've edited this into your post, while also removing two remaining "Maroon"s, if I have done something you don't agree with please feel free to rollback

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your teacher asked for a german reference, and not for a germane justification?

Was this a multiple choice question? Were you expected to provide any justification for your answer, any details explaining your thinking: If the answer is "yes", why it is so, and if the answer is "no", why "no"?

There is one possible interpretation of your question, under which the answer is "false". But, your question generally makes no sense to me, and perhaps there was 
some misunderstanding between you and your teacher, and you should ask your teacher for help, and for a clarification.

Some authors use notation $B\supset A$ to mean that $B$ is a proper superset of $A$, that is $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, meaning $A\subseteq B$ but $A\not=B$.

Also, usually one would think that $a\le b$, or even that $a<b$, when interval notation $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$ is used, but perhaps this is not a requirement in general. 
If $b<a$ then $[a,b]=\varnothing=(a,b)$.

So, suppose your question is interpreted as follows. 
Is it true that for every choice of $a$ and $b$ the interval $[a,b]$ properly contains the interval $(a,b)$, i.e. $(a,b)\subseteq[a,b]$ and $[a,b]\neq(a,b)$. The answer is no. Indeed, $[2,1]$ contains $(2,1)$ but not properly, since 
$[2,1]=\varnothing=(2,1)$.

I do not know if the above might or might not be a correct explanation why you and your teacher do not agree. Again, I recommend asking for a clarification. Why would your teacher need any reference (and if they need one, why German)? Didn't your teacher teach this material? Or did your teacher ask students to teach themselves, e.g. finding definitions, answers and references online? There is something in your questions that doesn't make sense to me.

Sometimes students use notation like $(-1,-\infty)$ assuming that it means the same as $(-\infty,-1)$. It is not the same. Perhaps something like this would provide an explanation for the apparent disagreement?

Perhaps your teacher didn't ask for a german reference, but for a more *germane* justification.

Choose the Right Synonym for germane :
RELEVANT, GERMANE, MATERIAL, PERTINENT, APPOSITE, APPLICABLE, APROPOS mean relating to or bearing upon the matter in hand. RELEVANT implies a traceable, significant, logical connection.  found material relevant to her case GERMANE may additionally imply a fitness for or appropriateness to the situation or occasion.  a point not germane to the discussion  MATERIAL implies so close a relationship that it cannot be dispensed with without serious alteration of the case.  facts material to the investigation PERTINENT stresses a clear and decisive relevance.  a pertinent observation  APPOSITE suggests a felicitous relevance.  add an apposite quotation to the definition APPLICABLE suggests the fitness of bringing a general rule or principle to bear upon a particular case.  the rule is not applicable in this case  APROPOS suggests being both relevant and opportune.  the quip was apropos